# saving thumbnail image to directory

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Hi I'm going to save thumbnail image get from video to directory with the time duration and with video icon just like

[image]

How it could be possible to save like this. 
I'm using the code to save image to directory and later I'll display it in GridView.

```
if ([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
    {    

        // Getting Time Duration of video file

        NSURL* videoUrl =  alassetRep.url;
        AVURLAsset *avUrl = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:videoUrl];
        CMTime time = [avUrl duration];

        NSUInteger dTotalSeconds = ceil(time.value/time.timescale);

        NSUInteger dMinutes = floor(dTotalSeconds % 3600 / 60);
        NSUInteger dSeconds = floor(dTotalSeconds % 3600 % 60);

        NSString *videoDurationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i", dMinutes, dSeconds];
        NSLog(@"%@",videoDurationText);

        /************************************Low Resolution Images ******************************************/
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[alassetRep fullResolutionImage]];
        UIImage *thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];

        NSData *thumbImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage, 0.8);

        NSString *thumbOriginalPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SMALL_IMAGE_%d_%d.jpg",(int)currentDate,i];
        NSString* thumbImagePath = [DucPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:thumbOriginalPath];
        NSLog(@"Image path At Save Time:%@",thumbImagePath);
        [thumbImageData writeToFile:thumbImagePath atomically:YES];

        [pMediaArray addObject:thumbOriginalPath];
    }
```

Comment: Well ideally you would just store the metadata and reconstruct your image view once you get all data. Why would you need to store the image exactly as it is? After all, the video icon is common, the image view is common. The image should obviously be some URL from an array or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've found solution....

```
if ([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
    {


        unsigned long DataSize = (unsigned long)[alassetRep size];
        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(DataSize);
        NSUInteger buffered = (NSUInteger)[alassetRep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)alassetRep.size error:nil];
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

        NSString* newVideoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%d_%d.mov",(int)currentDate,i];
        NSString* newVideoPath = [DucPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:newVideoName];
        [videoData writeToFile:newVideoPath atomically:YES];

        [pImageMediaArray addObject:newVideoName];
        NSLog(@"%@",newVideoName);


        // Getting Time Duration of video file

        NSURL* videoUrl =  alassetRep.url;
        AVURLAsset *avUrl = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:videoUrl];
        CMTime time = [avUrl duration];

        NSUInteger dTotalSeconds = ceil(time.value/time.timescale);

        NSUInteger dMinutes = floor(dTotalSeconds % 3600 / 60);
        NSUInteger dSeconds = floor(dTotalSeconds % 3600 % 60);

        NSString *videoDurationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i", dMinutes, dSeconds];
            /************************************Low Resolution Images ******************************************/
        UIImage *lowResImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[alassetRep fullResolutionImage]];
        UIImage *thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:lowResImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];

        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ CGPointZero, thumbImage.size}];
        imageView.image = thumbImage;
        UIImageView* timeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.size.width - 35, imageView.frame.size.height - 20, 30, 15)];
        timeView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen2-videoTime-icon.png"];

        UIImageView* videoIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+5, imageView.frame.size.height - 15, 15, 10)];
        videoIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen2-video-icon.png"];

        UILabel* timelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 15)];
        timelabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        timelabel.text = videoDurationText;
        timelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        timelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 10.0];

        [timeView addSubview:timelabel];
        [timeView bringSubviewToFront:timelabel];
        [imageView addSubview:videoIcon];
        [imageView addSubview:timeView];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [imageView.layer renderInContext:context];
        UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSData *thumbImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenShot, 0.8);

        NSString *thumbOriginalPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SMALL_IMAGE_%d_%d.jpg",(int)currentDate,i];
        NSString* thumbImagePath = [DucPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:thumbOriginalPath];
        NSLog(@"Image path At Save Time:%@",thumbImagePath);
        [thumbImageData writeToFile:thumbImagePath atomically:YES];

        [pMediaArray addObject:thumbOriginalPath];
    }
```